# file_get_contents URL now too long

Tags: php

I believe something with my hosting company may of changed recently as it was previously working. However, they are useless.

I have use `file_get_contents` which loads in a file.. to be honest it was part of an code pack that I'm not 100% what it does. However, the url is fairly length, it simply echos out the result of the file:

i.e

```
$custom = getRealIpAddr()."|||||".$_SESSION['cart']."|||||".makeSafe($_GET['i'])."|||||".$lang;
$pphash = create_paypal_hash(makeSafe($_SESSION['cart']), '', create_password('####'), $custom);
$tosend = base64_encode(urlencode($pphash));
$cgi = "http://www.***********.com/pl/b.pl?a=".$tosend; // TEST LINE
echo file_get_contents($cgi);
```

This results in a URL of about 390 characters.. if I trim it down to about 360 characters it works fine - however that isn't a solution as I lose some of the GET data passed into the file.

Any ideas what may of changed on my host thats now causing url's over 360 characters to throw a 403 forbidden error?

I've also tried it the curl method - which also gives the same result:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cgi);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Try with the CURL extension?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is on the server that you try to load from? Try to load that page with all the param in the browser.

Comment: Are you connecting to your own host or could the change be in another site you are trying to reach? If on your own box & using `suhosin`, you may want to check `suhosin.get.max_value_length`.

Comment: Wrikken - it is the same host. When i try and go to the url manually it also gives a 403 forbidden

Comment: @user2183216 what hosting company is it?

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1

*Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations might not properly support these lengths.*

This means you need to avoid using GET longer then 255.

As you have noticed some server (yours) do not go over 255 (360 in your case).

Use POST.

With CURL:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$vars = 'var1=' . $var1 . '&var2=' . $var2;

$con = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$re = curl_exec($con);
```

Without CURL:

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

Comment: how can i post to a file_get_contents function?

As i mentioned previously, i'm not 100% what this file does - all i know is that it takes the 'a' as a GET. How can i convert this to a POST Instead?

Comment: You cannot change a GET request into POST request if you cannot change the server implementation to accept both interchangeably. It might work if the server already accepts it, but more likely it will not.